# Rails 4 redirect links to ip address on Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, russian-doll-caching, cache-digests

I have an interesting problem. I use Russian-doll cache (cache_digests) on Rails 4 with Redis. After a period time, most of the links on pages change like this: "domain/url" to "server_ip/url"

It's fixed when I flush Redis.

How can I solve this problem?